Google Appointment schedule embed postMessage to the parent window
I am building a SaaS called Youform where we provide calendar embed for scheduling. Currently we provide Calendly, Cal.com and SavvyCal integration. Now I want to add the Google Scheduling Tool embed as well.
The only issue is that I don't find a way to get the "booked" event in my parent window.
All the other 3 I mentioned provides this.
I have checked the JS embed code of the Google Appointment and there seems to be no message option.
Anybody tried this before?
    <!-- Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling begin -->
<link href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.js" async></script>
<script>
(function() {
  var target = document.currentScript;
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    calendar.schedulingButton.load({
      url: 'YOUR_LINK',
      color: '#039BE5',
      label: 'Book an appointment',
      target,
    });
  });
})();
</script>
<!-- end Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling -->

Here is the pen.
Please replace YOUR_LINK with your appointment link which can be found here.
